# FFMPEG Desktop recording results in multiple files

Tags: ffmpeg

I am recording the desktop and I wanted the file name to be the timestamp. I went into many issues but finally got it working with the following:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 2.14748e+09 -i video="screen-capture-recorder":audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 60 "%%Y-%%m-%%d-%%H-%%M-%%S.mp4"
```

With this command I dont get one output.mp4, instead I get multiple files each files length varies between 15sec to 55sec. I'm not sure how to adjust it but I think its within `-f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 60` can anyone help with that?

If I remove the line `-f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 60` I dont get the file name as timestamp, I get the file name exactly `%%Y-%%m-%%d-%%H-%%M-%%S.mp4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The job of the segment muxer is to split the output into segments. Normally, it does this at video keyframes closest to the specified segment time. To avoid any splits, set segment time higher than recording time e.g. `-segment_time 9999`.